# "Ta gueule!" in a comedy movie

Tags: jurons, jeux-de-mots

In the movie [RRRrrrr!!!](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0357111/) (available on Netflix France) there is a recurrent use of the curse "Ta gueule !". I cannot understand if there is a word play going on or it is just for the sake of it.

The context is the following. During the *Âge de pierre*, the man charged of the patrol at dusk says: "Ça va  être tout noir !" to the people he meets during his round. Every people then answers: "Ta gueule !".

Does "ta gueule" here just means shut up, or there is a word play that I do not understand?

Comment: No puns here. Just that he is stating the obvious, and nobody wants to do his job (useless).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a word play? Does it just mean shut up

There are none. This is just the tradition in this movie. And yeah, it just means shut up.

For information, some people now shout loudly "TA GUEULE !" when someone use the sentence "Ca va être tout noir". ^^

Comment: The tradition in this movie??

Comment: @Lambie It's kind of a absurd comedy genre, so yes ^^

Answer (score 2):

Dans ce contexte "ta gueule" peut tout simplement se traduire par "shut up".
Il n'y a pas de jeu de mots, mais "ça va être tout noir" est devenu un mème en français.

Voici l'extrait en question :
[Ca va être tout noir! TA GUEULE! rrr (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnSelKDe4sE)

Answer (score 0):

Yes "Ta gueule" is the short way for "Ferme ta gueule" and it's really rude and irrespectful, specially when said loudly. I don't know the real translation for it. "shut up" just means "tais-toi" ... a little bit less irrespectful!
But "ta gueule" when said gently with a smile can be quite sweet in fact.

Comment: A translation would be "shut the fuck up", or "shut the hell up" on the less rude end of the rudeness spectrum. Also, I wouldn't translate shut up with "tais-toi" but rather "fermes la" or "la ferme!", which is more or a curse than "tais-toi".